# Microsoft Bot Teams error "SSO is not enabled for bot on Teams channel."

Tags: python-3.x, azure, authentication, botframework, microsoft-teams

SSO is not enabled for bot on Teams channel.

I develop a bot on Bot Framework and Azure Service, using python 3.7. I needed user authentication in the Microsoft system to use Graph API, etc.

Previously successfully used the [example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python) 18.bot-authentication and 24.bot-authentication-msgraph.

And this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Cpython)
I got the error “SSO is not enabled for bot”. I created new certificates and a new server with a bot, for the source code example 18.bot-authentication. Created a new channel in Azure and try to login from Teams, but have the same problem. In Bot Emulator and test in web-chat both authentications work. Teams want SSO.

Any tips? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-end-user-authentication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/configuration-end-user-authentication

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/publication-add-bot-to-microsoft-teams

The second article explains step by step how you can set a PVA bot to use in Microsoft Teams.

Please be aware of this part:
"Currently, if your bot supports end-user authentication, the user will not be able to explicitly sign out. This will fail the Microsoft Teams AppSource certification if you are publishing your bot in the Seller Dashboard. This does not apply to personal or tenant usage of the bot. Learn more at Publish your Microsoft Teams app and AppSource Validation Policy."

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Teams-Auth [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/46.teams-auth) and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample)  which helps you get started with authenticating a bot in Microsoft Teams as Teams behaves slightly differently than other channels. Presently, you can enable [Single Sign-On(SSO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso) in a custom tab. Microsoft Teams is currently working on the feature to enable SSO for bots.